# Como pegar o tamanho total de caracteres de uma coluna SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Quero pegar o tamanho total de caracteres que um coluna suportam, exemplo `INT` suporta 10 caracteres.

Tentei usar `DATALENGTH` que **não retorna a quantidade de caracteres**, mas a quantidade de *bytes* que a coluna ocupa.

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(CAMPO) FROM TABELA
```

Comment: a qual Banco de dados você se refere?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Sua interpretação do retorno está equivocada. A função retorna o tamanho em BYTES da coluna. No caso um valor do tipo INT ocupa quatro bytes no MSSql. O tamanho dos campos numéricos não são medidos em "caracteres" mas em bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça uma consulta nas seguintes tabelas:

- `sys.types`
- `sys.all_columns`

Segue a consulta

```
SELECT cNmColuna = C.name
    ,cTpColuna = UPPER(TYPE_NAME(C.user_type_id))
    ,iMaxDigit = CASE
                    WHEN T.precision = 0
                    THEN C.max_length
                    ELSE T.precision
                 END
FROM sys.all_columns C WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN sys.types T WITH(NOLOCK) ON T.user_type_id = C.user_type_id
    WHERE C.object_id = Object_Id('Nome da Tabela')
```

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o artigo:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

`int` suporta 10 caracteres:

```
Máximo: 2.147.483.647
Mínimo: -2.147.483.648
```

Dinamicamente falando, o SQL Server só consegue contar caracteres de campos próprios de caracteres (`varchar`, `nvarchar`, `text`, etc.). De campos numéricos, vale seguir a tabela de intervalos do link.

Comment: Então não existe uma função onde eu passe o tipo e ele me retorne o length máximo do campo?

Comment: Para numéricos, não. O que você pode fazer, se o tipo for `numeric`, é retornar a precisão e a escala (parte decimal e parte fracionária), mas isso não é o mesmo que `length` (extensão).

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando a deixa, `DATALENGTH` possui comportamentos variados, dependendo do tipo de dados que utiliza, exemplo:

```
DECLARE @exemploChar char(30)
SET @exemploChar = 'stack'

SELECT DATALENGTH(@exemploChar)
```

No exemplo acima, a coluna, exemplificada pela variável `@exemploChar`, receberá o tamanho total determinado na coluna, porque o tipo de dados `char` possui tamanho fixo, ou seja, ele ocupará 30 bytes (1 byte por caractere), mesmo que o conteúdo da coluna, ocupe, como no nosso exemplo, apenas 5 caracteres.

```
DECLARE @exemploVarchar varchar(30)
SET @exemploVarchar = 'stack'

SELECT DATALENGTH(@exemploVarchar)
```

No exemplo acima, criamos a coluna, exemplificada pela variável `@exemploVarchar`, com o tipo de dados `varchar`. Como se trata de um tipo de dados variável, o tamanho utilizado foi de apenas 5 bytes (5 caracteres) e não os 30 (1 byte por caractere) predeterminados na criação.

Por curiosidade, farei mais dois exemplos, mas usando unicode.

```
DECLARE @exemploNchar nchar(30)
SET @exemploNchar = 'stack'

SELECT DATALENGTH(@exemploNchar)
```

Para esse, podemos notar que o tamanho da coluna dobrou para 60 bytes consumidos. Isso acontece porque o tipo de dados unicode consome dois bytes por carácter e não um.

```
DECLARE @exemploNvarchar nvarchar(30)
SET @exemploNvarchar = 'stack'

SELECT DATALENGTH(@exemploNvarchar)
```

Por fim, neste exemplo o consumo será de 10 bytes (2 bytes por caractere).

Caso esteja se perguntando, quando usar um ou outro:

- `char` é bom para escrita, pois o tamanho da coluna já é determinado, não havendo a necessidade de um processamento extra para essa tarefa.
- `varchar` é bom para leitura, pois em 90% dos casos, o tamanho da coluna será menor que o tamanho predeterminado
- `unicode` é bom de ser utilizado, quando está fazendo importação de dados de outra base ou precisa tratar caracteres especiais a nossa língua. Neste caso, o unicode não tenta fazer a conversão, mantendo o dado original, além de ganhar velocidade.

Vale lembrar que se deseja ver as propriedades de uma tabela, e nela ver o tamanho determinado para cada coluna, poderá usar os comandos abaixo:

- `sp_help [nome_objeto]`*

  *objeto precisa estar no mesmo schema usado pelo login
- `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Selecionar o objeto e com o teclado, apertar `ALT + F1`

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi a solução é consultar a tabela de metadados e ver a definição do tipo e tamanho do campo.

Estas tabelas, claro, mudam conforme o Banco de Dados. 
Para maiores detalhes, consulte a documentação.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF ((SELECT character_maximum_length FROM information_schema.columns WHERE (table_name = 'SUC_CONFIG') AND (COLUMN_NAME = 'SUC_CHAVE')) < 100)
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE SUC_CONFIG ALTER COLUMN [SUC_CHAVE] VARCHAR(100) NULL
    END
GO
```

Comment: Qual o propósito de alterar o tipo e tamanho da coluna?